# Deleting a VPN Connection

Tags: c#, vpn

After I disconnect from the vpn using this code `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "My_VPN /d");` It still shows on the VPN Connection list. How can I remove it from there through my program?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete VPN connection you need to delete file "**rasphone.pbk**" or section with **[VPN Name]** in this file. The file is INI file with extension PBK.

By default the file located in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk

After delete operation you will need to restart "**explorer.exe**"

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by using WMI's [PS_VpnConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vpnclientpsprov/ps-vpnconnection)  class.

```cs
using System.Management; // need to add a reference to the assembly [System.Management]

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string WMIScope = "root/Microsoft/Windows/RemoteAccess/Client";
        const string WMIClass = "PS_VpnConnection";

        using (var cls = new ManagementClass(WMIScope, WMIClass, null))
        using (var methodParams = cls.GetMethodParameters("Remove"))
        {
            methodParams["Name"] = new[]{"your_vpn_name"};
            methodParams["Force"] = true;

            cls.InvokeMethod("Remove", methodParams, null);
        }
    }
}
```